# Как включить учетную запись администратора?

Tags: windows

Как включить учетную запись администратора, если нет админ доступа. И комп работает только под user и ничего невозможно сделать. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

пуск->Завершение сеанса. далее если не выскочит окно с выбором юзера нажать **Контрол альт делит** и ввести в строку пользователя имя **Администратор**

Значит *правой кнопкой мыши на значке мой компьютер*, если права позволят.

Там *выбрать учетные* записи и *включить запись админ*а.

Comment: пишет что учетный запись администратора отключен. так не получается

Comment: обновил ответ.

Comment: вот именно что нет прав для этого мне нужна активировать учетный запись администратора

Comment: Тогда оставь надежду либо ищи граберы чтобы при загрузке с диска поменять свойства. Дисков таких в нете море!

Answer (score 1):

[Супер администратор в Windows 7](http://nikpro.wordpress.com/2009/05/06/super-admin-windows-7/)